# Asking for an input and printing in a C interface for R

Tags: r, c

I'm trying to modify a CRAN package. From what I understand, they use a C interface using `.Call()`.
So I made changes in the C code (can't do it anywhere else since it's in a loop) but I need to ask the user to input an integer.

I read the ["Writing R extension"](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) doc and found out that you need to use specific functions as `Rprintf()` instead of `printf()`.

But I can't seem to find a way to replace `scanf()` so how can we ask for an input?

> *And finally is `Rprintf()` supposed to print in the R console because it is what I'd want but I can't find where it is printed?*

Edit:
I'm unable to try it right now but it may seem that using `capture_output()` may work to get the `Rprintf()` output. Therefore the only remaining issue would be the `scanf()` :)

Thanks a lot!